# How to connect polkadot.js to the Parastate local node

Tags: blockchain

I'm trying to connect my local node here:
https://polkadot.js.org/apps/
I go to the top left coner and choosing "local node "
However I do not understand where to enter ip and port for my node.
How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Enable ssh tunneling to the server.
The first step is to enable ssh tunnel from the local host to the remote server where your parastate node has been hosted . The below command enable ssh tunnel to remote host xx.xx.xx.xx on port 9944 which is needed for polakdot.js.org endpoint:

ssh -N -L 9944:127.0.0.1:9944 -i C:\Users\sshkey\privatekey.ppk root@xx.xx.xx.xx

In case you are not using ssh key and would like to connect using traditional method by supplying password, use the below option

ssh -N -L 9944:127.0.0.1:9944 root@xx.xx.xx.xx

Answer (score 0):

The below command enable ssh tunnel to remote host xx.xx.xx.xx on port 9944 which is needed for polakdot.js.org endpoint
ssh -N -L 9944:127.0.0.1:9944 -i C:\Users\sshkey\privatekey.ppk root@xx.xx.xx.xx
In case you are not using ssh key and would like to connect using traditional method by supplying password , use the below option
ssh -N -L 9944:127.0.0.1:9944 root@xx.xx.xx.xx
Enter the password when prompted/
You will just have empty hanging window . Don’t panic you are all good.